# Cannot sync with any NTP server on windows 10

Tags: windows, ntp

I'm trying to sync my windows10 with ANY NTP server but whatever server I use, I'm always receiving timeout.

I have tryed setting few different server in "Internet time settings" but in every try i got "connection timeout"

When i try to resync with command `w32tm /resync /rediscover` I got different response, that is:
`The computer did not resync because no time data was available.`

BUT when i try `w32tm /stripchart /computer:0.pl.pool.ntp.org /dataonly`
response is:

```
The current time is 19.03.2020 14:04:59.
14:04:59, -24.5643160s
14:05:01, -24.5642918s
.
.
.
```

which i suppose is correct

of course I have also tryed manually configuring peers

```
w32tm /configure /manualpeerlist:"0.pl.pool.ntp.org 1.pl.pool.ntp.org 2.pl.pool.ntp.org 3.pl.pool.ntp.org" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
net stop w32time
net start w32time
w32tm /resync
```

but again:

```
Sending resync command to local computer
The computer did not resync because no time data was available.
```

I have tryed disabling firewall/antivirus and opening ports (UDP 123 and UDP/TCP 6001-6035) which i found in other answers but nothing gave me working answer.

Side note:
My PC doesn't sync for about 4 and a half year

[image]
"Last successful time synchronization: 01.08.2015"

**Update**:
Result of `w32tm /query /configuration` command

```
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 5 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 1 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 360000 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 32768 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: 0.pl.pool.ntp.org 1.pl.pool.ntp.org 2.pl.pool.ntp.org 3.pl.pool.ntp.org (Local)

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
```

Comment: Does the same occur if you use the IP of the router to sync against?

Comment: @JW0914 yes, same mesage every time

Comment: Please provide the (English) output of `w32tm /query /configuration` and update your question

Comment: @Ramhound updated

Comment: Please provide the relevant information (English) from ntpDebug.log by running `w32tm /debug /enable /file:c:\temp\ntpDebug.log /size:102400 /entries:0-300` and update your question

Comment: @Ramhound i got an error `the following error occurred: System cannot find specified path. (0x80070003)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot tell if this will help anyone but I have managed to find the issue.

My ISP is blocking ntp servers for some reason.