# My Windows time changes to the future and causes problems. How can I fix this?

Tags: windows, motherboard, updates, time, bitdefender

My Windows time changes to the future (this last time somewhere in 2042).

- My system is: X570S Aorus Master @Bios Gigabyte 4.21.1027.1
- My OS is: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155] (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
- Output of `w32tm /query /peers` is:

  ```
  C:\Users\vncvnvn>w32tm /query /peers
  #Peers: 1
  Peer: time.windows.com,0x9
  NState:
  Active Time Remaining: 28602.0109858s Mode: 3 (Client)    Stratum: 3 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
  PeerPoll Interval: 17 (out of valid range) HostPoll Interval: 10 (1024s)
  ```

**Provide details and any research**

1. **Bitdefender subscription**

   As a result my Bitdefender thinks it's subscription is out of date and stops functioning telling me to renew.
2. **Microphone and webcam warning**

   Also in Bitdefender on 21-02-2024 I had a warning with time-stamp *11-11 2023 at 11:11* my "Status monitormodule microphone" was altered (turned off) and a second warning at the same time, my "Status monitormodule webcam" was turned off.

   Logfile item Bitdefender turned off:

   ```
   - System 
   - Provider 
   [ Name]  SecurityCenter 
   - EventID 15 
   [ Qualifiers]  0 
   Version 0 
   Level 4 
   Task 0 
   Opcode 0 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
   - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2042-02-02T01:45:04.1019529Z 
   EventRecordID 42084 
   Correlation 
   - Execution 
   [ ProcessID]  11716 
   [ ThreadID]  0 
   Channel Application 
   Computer ffff 
   Security 
   - EventData 
    Bitdefender Firewall 
    SECURITY_PRODUCT_STATE_OFF
   ```
3. **Browser logged off**

   All browsers Windows that I had open logged out (e.g. gmail accounts and stuff) Also: **The browser (Brave) is out of date all of a sudden and "unable to update update" anymore "reinstall"** (I always update instantly)
4. **Warnings deleted**

   Bitdefender warnings were automatically deleted (just not there anymore) after aprox 30 min. I have screenshots though.
5. **Log files**

   In the log files you can see when the time gets reset. The first logentry after is:

   > "The EventSystem sub system is suppressing duplicate event log entries for a duration of 86400 seconds.  The suppression timeout can be controlled by a REG_DWORD value named SuppressDuplicateDuration under the following registry key: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\EventSystem\EventLog."
6. In the applicationlog files you can see what happens after the time gets reset
   Updates of the motherboard (Gigabyte Updateservice), the gpu (gupdate) and some other things like ESENT.

**When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried**

1. I reset the time manually.
2. I resubscribe Bitdefender which then turns on again.
3. Look at logfiles only to find out I don't get things very well.
4. Use malwarebytes, bitdefender for scans, Housecall to see what's on my network. But I seriously have no clue what I am doing here.

Basically I want to know why it is that this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: One of the usual causes is a bad CMOS battery. What is your computer model?

Comment: look at NTP settings. See, for example: ( https://superuser.com/questions/1533937/cannot-sync-with-any-ntp-server-on-windows-10 ) The user discovered his ISP was blocking NTP

Comment: Hi there Harrymc and Yorik, for some reason I haven't gotten an email that you guys replied. My pc is pretty new (1 year old) . So the model is a X570S Aorus Master @Bios Gigabyte 4.21.1027.1 App Center is installed as well as easytune and easytune engineservice ( I don't overclock btw)  What other information about my pc would you need? How do I test if my ISP blocks NTP servers?

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\vncvnvn>w32tm /query /peers
#Peers: 1

Peer: time.windows.com,0x9
State: Active
Time Remaining: 28602.0109858s
Mode: 3 (Client)
Stratum: 3 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
PeerPoll Interval: 17 (out of valid range)
HostPoll Interval: 10 (1024s)

Comment: @Wilbert Could be a faulty CMOS battery.

Comment: @Wilbert- You should format that information as an [edit] to your question instead of sumitting it as a unformatted comment.

Comment: @Wilbert Further to Giacomo1968's comment, a replacement CR2032 cell for the CMOS costs around $2 and it's easy to get to to replace - it's down at the bottom-right of the motherboard. Other than that, have you got any kind of game "cheat" software installed that might be adjusting the date?